# Scoped Storage - Download folder access

Tags: android, android-download-manager, storage-access-framework, android-10.0, scoped-storage

I am targeting android 10 and I don't use `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage`. I use the `DownloadManager` to download into the download folder via: `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName)`. I listen to the download-complete-broadcast, extract the uri (`file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/<name>.pdf`) and open it in a pdf-reader via `FileProvider`. It works... why? Isn't it supposed to NOT work since android 10 and scoped storage? Why am I allowed to access files in the download-folder?

EDIT: `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).listFiles()` lists all Files although the doc says:

> To improve user privacy, direct access to shared/external storage devices is deprecated. When an app targets Q, the path returned from this method is no longer directly accessible to apps

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped. Downloaded documents and e-books do not require additional permissions.

Comment: When you use SAF, which I don't

Comment: As an experiment, try downloading an image or other file type to see if you still have access.

Comment: No difference, I still can open it from the downloads folder

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/61886002/4685284

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was the solution:

> If an app is installed with legacy external storage enabled, the app remains in this mode until it's uninstalled.

Changing the flag and restarting the app does not work.

**Edit**: Since a source was requested. The page changed since when I saw it first, so the quote is not 100% correct anymore, but still: [In the blue box](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#migrate-legacy-storage)

Comment: Source for this?