# PDF viewer permission issue in android 11

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-external-storage, android-fileprovider, accessibility

I am opening pdf file using an external pdf viewer application. But in android 11 shows eacces
permission denied issue. All permissions already declared in my manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Also declared this :

android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Creating and writing the content with below code :

```
byte [] decodedContent = Base64.decode(base64.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

                try {

                    File pdfDirPath = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath(), "pdfs");
                    File file5 = new File(pdfDirPath, globalData.getVin()+".pdf");

                    if (!file5.exists()) {

                        file5.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                    }

                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file5);
                    outputStream.write(Base64.decode(base64, Base64.NO_WRAP));
                    outputStream.close();
```

And open above file like this :

```
    Uri   path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".helper.ProviderClass", file5);
  intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: You can declare nothing for another app.

Comment: And your legacy request would also only work for your own app on an Android 10 device.

Comment: @blackapps then how to access another app to view PDF file?

Comment: In the normal way with ACTION_VIEW.

Comment: `shows eacces permission denied issue. ` Access to what? And where do you see that issue?

Comment: "I am opening pdf file using an external pdf viewer application" -- your [mcve] does not contain this code. If you are using `Uri.fromFile()`, that has been banned (effectively) since Android 7.0, and you need to switch to `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()`.

Comment: @blackapps updated question with full code

Comment: @CommonsWare I am also using FileProvider. Please see the updated question.

Comment: `file5.getParentFile().mkdirs();` Check the return value. And if false stop and display a toast to inform the user.

Comment: `if (!file5.exists())` That should be: `if (!file5.getParentFile().exists())`

Comment: And post the stacktrace. new FileOutputStream(file5); will throw an exception.

Comment: @blackapps  it returns true. So no exceptions available. It works fine on all other versions except android 11.

Comment: @blackapps updated the question with complete code.

Comment: ??? Nothing around mkdirs changed.

Comment: @blackapps no changes

Comment: Well if you dont want help.. ok. But then why do you post? `Please help me with this.` ?

Comment: @blackapps Why you commenting like this. please reply professionally. I meant, there is no impact after changing the mkdir as you mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two points.

1. android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" is ignored on Android 11. This version of Android enforces scoped storage regardless of this flag in your Manifest, so you can safely take it out because it has no effect on your device.
2. Because scoped storage is enforced, apps are not allowed to access other apps' private storage locations. In your case you are saving your file in getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() which is your app's private location. Scoped storage rules on Android 11 will prohibit your external PDF viewer app to open any file in your app's location.
   On Android 11 if you want another app to open a doc that your app created you have at least two choices and may be more.

a) A complicated  one. Use FileProvider https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider

b) This one is much simpler one. Since your intention is to share this file with another app, instead of writing into your app's specific directory you should use MediaStore API and write it into the MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI. There are many good examples on the net how to do it, for example [How to save pdf in scoped storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61692878/how-to-save-pdf-in-scoped-storage)
Your PDF Viewer should have no problem accessing it from there.